# What is recommended value for compressionMinSize for Tomcat 7?

Tags: performance, tomcat, compression

I understand it will depend on the below factors:

1. Increase in CPU usage with compression
2. Bandwidth (Using akamai etc. can be costly in terms of using more bandwidth)

Based on above factors and any others, what is the generally recommended value/range for compressionMinSize?

Does tomcat have pre-compression feature?

Comment: Related question:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/what-is-recommended-minimum-object-size-for-gzip-performance-benefits